# For loop to get information from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get image paths from several columns in a table. Identified in the $fileArray.
How ever the loop will run but only one string will be returned. The other six times it tries too return an empty string. The columns DO exist and the loop runs once retreiving the first path but fails to retrieve the rest. I am lost in what this bug could be. Thanks in advance.

```
    include 'Adds/add.php';
    $fileArray = array('Bags', 'Balls', 'Clubs', 'Gloves', 'Promos', 'Putts', 'Tees');
    for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++){
        $query = "SELECT " . $fileArray[$i] . " FROM images";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if (!$result)
        {
            echo "Database query Failed" . $result; // -------------------ERROR MESSAGE
        }
        $row_count = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($row_count == 0)
        {
            echo '<p style="color:red;">There are no images available</p>'; // ------------ERROR MESSAGE
        }elseif ($result)
        {
            $files = array();
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
            {
                $files[] =  $row[$fileArray[$i]];
            }
        }else echo "query failed"; // ------------------------------------------------------ERROR MESSAGE
        echo $files[$i] . "<br />";
    }
    echo count($files);
```

Database Structure:
Tees    Clubs   Promos  Putts   Balls   Gloves  Bags
1.jpg   2.jpg   1.jpg   1.jpg   1.jpg   1.jpg   1.jpg

Comment: There are no insert statements in this code

Comment: What is in `Adds/add.php`?

Comment: The add.php is just a connection code to the database.

Comment: John Conde - I am not exactly inserting anything, just retreiving information.

Comment: Could you show the database content? and the DB Structure?

Comment: Edited with database structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   elseif ($result) 
   {
      $files = array();
      ...
```

$files array can be recreated after  next iteration and can remove previous values.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $files[] =  $row[$fileArray[$i]];
}
```

Here you fill $files array. This array size can be very large. 
After it you echo $files[$i]; $i from 0 to 7. Is it correct?

I think here is incorrect logic.

Comment: Yes that was an obvious one thanks, i had been going all night at that. Should of slept on it. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

just before the while loop `$files = array();` is been overridden and gets back to empty array.
please declare `$files = array();` before `for loop`.
Try this it works just fine, just for the example i removed while loop.

```
$fileArray = array('Bags', 'Balls', 'Clubs', 'Gloves', 'Promos', 'Putts', 'Tees');
$files=array();
for($i=0;$i<count($fileArray);$i++){

$files[] = $fileArray[$i];
echo $files[$i] . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Sorry first in best dressed but i credited you a point. Thanks alot though, well done.